# Trying to add static block to customer logout page, block is displaying twice

Tags: static-block, local.xml, cms-block

How do I add a static CMS block to the customer logout page? I have it somewhat working, but the content of my CMS block shows twice:

1. I setup a CMS block called logout_message with a bit of html in there.
2. Added this to my local.xml

   ```
   <label>Customer Account Logout Success</label>

   <remove name="right"/>

   <remove name="left"/>

   <reference name="root">

       <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>

   </reference>

   <reference name="content">

       <block type="core/template" name="customer_logout" template="customer/logout.phtml">

           <block type="cms/block" name="logout_message" as="logout_message">

               <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>logout_message</block_id></action>

           </block>

       </block>

   </reference>
   ```
3. created my template/customer/logout.phtml:

   ```
   <div class="small-16 columns panel-fill ">

      <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('logout_message') ?>

   </div>
   ```

As I said the content of the static block shows twice - why? Small update - it actually outputs the content of the entire logout.phtml file, not just the CMS block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically re-inserting a `customer_logout` block in the content of the page.

Instead, it should be:

```
<reference name="customer_logout">        
    <block type="cms/block" name="logout_message" as="logout_message">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>logout_message</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: This does work if I place it in side the content reference - but not on it's own.  Where did you get the customer_logout reference from? Trying to "find" this stuff is irritating.

Comment: It's the "name" of the block you want to add/remove stuff to. If you check `page.xml`, you will see that all the structural blocks are defined there. So when you do a reference to `head` or `content`, you are actually referencing a block. Just like your example.